# How do I make my bot do something if a command hasn't been used for awhile in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to know how do make the bot say something in a channel if the "helloworld" command hasn't been used in 1 minute

````
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('connected')

# Command
@client.command()
async def helloworld(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello World!')

client.run(TOKEN)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html). I'm not sure if it will work as a command (since commands require invocation), but, given a channel ID, you can send the message to a specified channel repeatedly over some interval of time.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('connected')

@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def helloworld(channel_id=1234567890):
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send("Hello World!")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

The time interval argument passed to the `tasks.loop()` decorator can be `seconds=`, `minutes=`, or `hours=`.

[`discord.ext.tasks` API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#api-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task like [Jacob Lee specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069184/12451222) and add an extra element to check if hello world has been used.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
@client.event
async def on_command_completion(ctx):
    if ctx.command.name == 'helloworld':
         with open('invoke.json', 'r') as f:
               data = json.load(f)
         data['time'] = datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
         with open('invoke.json', 'w') as f:
               json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def check_hello():
    with open('invoke.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if 'time' in data.keys():
        if (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(data['time'], '%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')).total_seconds() > 60:
            if 'last_invoked' in data.keys():
                if datetime.strptime(data['last_invoked'], '%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') > datetime.strptime(data['time'], '%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'): 
                    return 
                channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
                await channel.send("Hello has not been used in a minute")
                data['last_invoked'] = datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
                with open('invoke.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(data)
```

References:-

- [on_command_completion](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_completion)